# C# UWP app error: "'InkStroke' does not contain a definition for 'StrokeStartedTime'"

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, touch, pen

I am making a UWP app in C# in Visual Studios 2015, that supports Windows v10.0.10240. However, when I try to access the StrokeStartedTime of the InkStroke class, I get the error listed in the title.

Comment: It would be useful if you include the sample code. Especially as to how you are accessing the property and including the InkStroke class in your code.

Comment: hmm, right now I don't need the answer for my app anymore, because there is actually a StrokeStarted event, but an answer would be otherwise useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `StrokeStartedTime` property is a newly added API that updated by [Windows 10 SDK Preview Build 15003 Released](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/13/windows-10-sdk-preview-build-15003-released/#ie87KHFukm0Sjd6l.97). You may require [Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) or higher and the UWP app need target "**Windows 10 Creators Update (10.0; Build 15063)**" or higher. More details please see section **API Updates and Additions** of the above release document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am using Visual Studios 2015 but I am a beginner and didn't know that was relevant.